# gtk_init() failed unexpected

Tags: gtk, x11, raspberry-pi

I am using raspberry pi with GTK+, means ARM+Debian+GTK+. But even the example of GTK website always fails in my environment. like:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int   argc,
      char *argv[] )
{
GtkWidget *window;

//gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
gtk_init_check(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_widget_show  (window);

gtk_main ();

return(0);
}
```

I compiled this with

```
gcc -g gtktest.cpp -o base `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs`
```

and successful. When running it, I got:

```
(base:12760): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(base:12760): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(base:12760): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(base:12760): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(base:12760): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion `GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed

(base:12760): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(base:12760): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(base:12760): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(base:12760): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

Only using gtk_init() will also cause an error.
I checked the DISPLAY variable and tried setting it to < my IP >:0.0 but no effect. I doubt this might be a problem that GTK cannot get the display resource, but I did not find a way to solve this.

FYI I am using putty SSH to the raspberryPi.

Comment: These errors are because gtk_init failed. you should check the return value of gtk_check_init and not continue any further.Not that this will solve your problem. Do other gtk applications work?

Comment: What gtk application could I use to test? For example?

Comment: Do you a XWindow server running in your computer? (the server is the display).

Comment: On what display do you want your application to show up?

Comment: I expect the application could show a screen on current terminal. I tried setting it to my ip address 0.0 but does not effect.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to launch an X instance in a terminal. You should run your application from within LXDE with a proper display plugged in. Are you new to Linux btw.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be quite new to the things you do, so there are 2 things that come to my mind

- (as already mentioned) you need a running xserver instance running
- does your `DISPLAY` bash variable yield the correct display (AFAIK gtk+-2.0 honors that, also make sure it is properly exported)
- `xhost +` to allow access from another terminal to your current xserver (**Note** this has serious security issues, for details read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_10_05.html and refer to the xhost manpage - no shortcuts!)

For details read http://www.hungry.com/~jamie/xexport.html

And be careful with xserver documentation/topics, there are tons of obsolete things out on the net.

Comment: Thank you. I am a newbie to the GUI stuff. Now I have installed a cygwin xwin server, and problem solved on remote server, and on local server, just use startx and xhost + could also resolve my issue. I did not realize there should be a server to accept the GUI instance:)